# loop in bash does not perform integer comparison properly

Tags: bash

I have below code

```
i=0
for s in / - \\ \| 
do 
  printf "\rWaiting for application start to finish $i $s"
  sleep 1
  ((i++))
  if [[ $i -gt 30 ]]
  then 
    break 
  fi
done
```

The loop always ends after 3 iterations.  Any reason as why?

Comment: can you show the full output when you run it ?

Comment: It loops up to 3 (4 iterations) because the arguments in the for loop are 4: '/', '-', '\' and '|', isn't it?

Comment: Waiting for application start to finish 3 |

Comment: Yeah, I think that' it. I've added more arguments to the array and it loops more times. Not sure how to solve it though

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=('/' '-' '\' '|')
for ((i = 0; i < 30; ++i)); do
    printf '\rWaiting for application start to finish %d %s' \
            "$i" "${a[i%4]}"
    sleep 1
done
echo
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.  The for loop which has three arguments is exiting instead of the if condition failing.

Comment: Why this has been posted as an answer?

Comment: @User123 Because it's the answer to the question?

Comment: The behavior was right and should not have been a question at all.   Therefore the answer.